# Mac's not reliably displaying horizontal scroll bars.

Tags: css

I'm at a loss as to why Mac's are refusing to display horizontal scroll bars reliably on overflowing elements. I'm not a frequent Mac user so this could just be me being stupid.

https://codepen.io/phawxby/pen/JrayeG

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Weirdly they don't display via browserstack but do display on the physical Mac next to me. Unfortunately we're getting reports of some users which are getting the issue too, obviously they're physical machines.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

High Sierra - Safari 11 Browserstack
[image]

High Sierra - Chrome 61 Browserstack
[image]

High Sierra - Safari 11 Physical
[image]

High Sierra - Chrome 61 Physical
[image]

Comment: What browser and browser version on a Mac? Safari, Chrome?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think you're problem is a system setting. You can "turn off" constantly scrollbars. Then they'll only be visible while you're actually scrolling in the browser and they don't take up any space in the viewport because they're 'on top' of the page, not besides.  It's in the system settings -> general -> display scrollbars (don't know the exact wording, as my system is set to german).

Comment: @deadfishli you are correct. It's a shame you didn't give that as a proper answer, you could've had the points.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have. Wasn't thinking I guess. I'll add it now and if you want to you can still accept it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mac OSX has a system setting to turn on and off constantly showing scroll bars. It can be found in the System Settings -> General -> "Display Scrollbars".

If "display scrollbars" is turned off, they'll only show up in the browser window while you're actually scrolling. That way you won't see them in overflowing containers unless you're scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link out for some examples of custom scrollbars - https://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO

```
ul::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

If you set display: inline and simply create your own scrollbar style, it should stay visible.